# Font Awesome Icon Issue : on Hover it's getting extra space belo

Tags: html, css

This is the code below. I tried my best .Please have a look. Both HTML and CSS is added. How to make a circular fontawesome icon along with text  below both in  anchor tag become large on hover. I 'm adding a markup for the html.

## CSS

```css
.navicon {
     margin: 0 auto;
     z-index: 999;
 }

    em.icon-text{
     line-height: normal;
     font-style: normal;
 }
    a.icon{
     text-decoration: none;
    }
   .exp{
     width:80px;
     height:80px;
     background-color:red;
     border-radius:100%;
     line-height:80px;
     text-align:center;
     vertical-align:middle;
     display: block;
     margin: 0 auto 0;
     
     z-index: 999;
     transition:.3s;
 }
  .exp:hover{
   position: relative;
   
   width:120px;
   height:120px;
   line-height:120px;
   transition:.3s;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 25px;
 }
 .fa-camera-retro{
  line-height: inherit;
 }
```

```html
Here is my html code:

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="navicon">
        <a href="#" class="exp">
            <i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-3x"></i>
            <em class="icon-text text-center">Creative</em>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: It's already getting large on hover, can you explain your question please?

Comment: @Sahil check  `.exp:hover` css rule

Comment: ok, so it was about centring the cam in the circle.

Comment: The problem, its getting extra space between the text and icon @Sahil

Answer (score 3):

you need to add line height to the `<i>` try

```
line-height: 80px;
vertical-align:middle;
```

---

```css
.navicon {
     margin: 0 auto;
     z-index: 999;
 }

    em.icon-text{
     line-height: normal;
     font-style: normal;
 }
    a.icon{
     text-decoration: none;
    }
   .exp{
     width:80px;
     height:80px;
     background-color:red;
     border-radius:100%;
     line-height:80px;
     text-align:center;
     vertical-align:middle;
     display: block;
     margin: 0 auto 0;
     
     z-index: 999;
     transition:.3s;
 }
  .exp:hover{
   position: relative;
   
   width:120px;
   height:120px;
   line-height:120px;
   transition:.3s;
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 25px;
 }
 .fa-camera-retro{
  line-height: inherit;
 }

   i{
     line-height:80px;
     vertical-align:middle;
   }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="navicon">
    <a href="#" class="exp">
        <i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-3x"></i>
        <em class="icon-text text-center">Creative</em>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I'm not getting any reason for the unwanted space between the icon and text. Please have a look.